# Loops optimization

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

I have a loop and inside a have a inner loop. How can I optimise it please in order to optimise execution time like avoiding accessing to memory many times to the same thing and avoid the maximum possible the addition and multiplication.

```
int n,m,x1,y1,x2,y2,cnst;
int N = 9600;
int M = 1800;
int temp11,temp12,temp13,temp14;
int temp21,temp22,temp23,temp24;
int *arr1 = new int [32000]; // suppose it's already filled
int *arr2 = new int [32000];// suppose it's already filled

int sumFirst = 0;
int maxFirst = 0;
int indexFirst = 0;
int sumSecond = 0;
int maxSecond = 0;
int indexSecond = 0;
int jump = 2400;
for( n = 0; n < N; n++)
{
    temp14 = 0;
    temp24 = 0;
    for( m = 0; m < M; m++)
    {
        x1 = m + cnst;
        y1 = m + n + cnst;
        temp11 = arr1[x1];
        temp12 = arr2[y1];
        temp13 = temp11 * temp12;
        temp14+= temp13;
        
        x2 = m + cnst + jump;
        y2 = m + n + cnst + jump;
        temp21 = arr1[x2];
        temp22 = arr2[y2];
        temp23 = temp21 * temp22;
        temp24+= temp23;
    }

    sumFirst += temp14;
    if (temp14 > maxFirst)
    {
        maxFirst = temp14;
        indexFirst = m;
    }
    
    sumSecond += temp24;
    if (temp24 > maxSecond)
    {
        maxSecond = temp24;
        indexSecond = n;
    }
}

// At the end we use sum , index and max for first and second;
```

Comment: Use your toolchain's profiler.

Comment: Please use better identifiers than `temp11` and `temp12` - how are we supposed to know what they represent?

Comment: First thing: did you compile your code with optimizations enabled? Compilers are quite good at doing that for you, maybe you can get away with that. You should verify different levels of optimizations if the result will be satisfactory.

Comment: no massaging of the code can avoid a nested loop when the algorithm needs a nested loop. Optimization is mainly about choosing the right algorithm (ie a different one when the current one is not performant enough) and turning on compiler optimizations.

Comment: Oops... optimization is complex. As a C++ programmer, you should not think about code level optimization (the compiler is generally smarter than you), but only of algorithmic optimization. Without the specification of what this code should do, and a description of the algorithm, it is hard to have an advice on it. Only when you trust your algo to be efficient enough, and if the performances do not meet what is required, you should profile the application to identify the bottlenecks. Then the possible actions really depend of what you will find on that last analysis...

Comment: ... And please never forget that prematurate optimization is generally seen as poor practice because it leads to code that will be hard to read and to maintain.

Comment: One way to improve performance in general is to use SIMD where possible.

Comment: I thing i didn't explain very well my problem. It's an algorithmic optimazation and I think it's very specific. Thank u guys anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are multiplying array elements and accumulating the result.
This can be optimized by:

- SIMD (doing multiple operations at a single CPU step)
- Parallel execution (using multiple physical/logical CPUs at once)

Look for CPU-specific SIMD way of doing this. Like `_mm_mul_epi32` from SSE4.1 can possibly be used on x86-64. Before trying to write your own SIMD version with compiler intrinsics, make sure the compiler doesn't do it already for you.

As for parallel execution, look into omp, or using C++17 parallel accumulate.

Comment: The question is about options to optimize inner loop, not about algorithm. This site is about answering questions, not about giving advice.

Comment: Uuuuh, I hit a nerve. You should read about X-Y problems. But no worries. You gave a very clever and higly sophisticated answer. That was an indeed very good.answer. I am absolutely sure that the OP will have a big benfit out of that. And because the answer is that good, I will upvote it, so +1

Comment: I thing i didn't explain very well my problem. It's an algorithmic optimazation and I think it's very specific. Thank u guys anyway.